# t-statistic for the above samples, and display the t-score and p-value in separate lines

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

The data set s1 represents consumption with stimulation, and s2 without simulation.

```py
s1 = [12, 7, 3, 11, 8, 5, 14, 7, 9, 10]
s2 = [8, 7, 4, 14, 6, 7, 12, 5, 5, 8]
```

Compute t-statistic for the above samples, and display the t-score and p-value in separate lines.

Hint: Use the `ttest_rel` function available in `scipy`

```py
from scipy import stats
s1 = [12, 7, 3, 11, 8, 5, 14, 7, 9, 10]
s2 = [8, 7, 4, 14, 6, 7, 12, 5, 5, 8]
t, p = stats.ttest_rel(s1, s2)
print(t, p)
```

I am not getting actual output and it is not getting passed.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Anyone please help me in this..

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got the following output: (t,p) = 1.315587028960544, 0.2208380130273219. Are you sure you have scipy installed? What output are you getting?

To get t and p values on seperate lines I just seperated the print statement:

```
from scipy import stats

s1 = [12, 7, 3, 11, 8, 5, 14, 7, 9, 10]
s2 = [8, 7, 4, 14, 6, 7, 12, 5, 5, 8]
t, p = stats.ttest_rel(s1, s2)
print(t)
print(p)
```

Comment: Problem Statement
A researcher noted the number of chocolate chips consumed by 10 rats, with and without electrical stimulation.

The data set s1 represents consumption with stimulation, and s2 without simulation.

s1 = [12, 7, 3, 11, 8, 5, 14, 7, 9, 10]
s2 = [8, 7, 4, 14, 6, 7, 12, 5, 5, 8]
Compute t-statistic for the above samples, and display the t-score and p-value in separate lines.

Hint: Use the ttest_rel function available in scipy

Comment: That is the problem statement but I am not passing that please help me @Brandon

Comment: Did you try the code I listed above? Might even be worth swapping your arguments in the ttest_rel function. I think it might be because you print your t and p value in the same line versus separate lines as directed in the problem statement.